# R. dplyr left_join produces column with only NAs. All columns are characters

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join, na

I have 2 data frames, A & B. A has ~1400000 rows and B has ~1700000 rows. In both data frames, all columns are characters.

They were imported in this way:

```
A = read.table('A.txt', sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)
B = read.table('B.txt', sep = "\t", stringsAsFactors = F)
```

A:

```
CHR    POSITION    SNP    REF    ALT
1      49554       rs53   A      G
1      564672      rs56   A      C
1      5668        rs21   C      T
1      5680        rs61   A      G
```

B:

```
Illumina            SNP
10:1000122-GT       rs53
10:1000111-CT       rs56
10:10004568-TCTC-T  rs21
10:100065656-GA     rs61
```

When I do left_join by "SNP"

```
C = left_join(A, B, by = "SNP")
```

I get:

```
CHR    POSITION    SNP    REF    ALT    Illumina
1      49554       rs53   A      G      NA
1      564672      rs56   A      C      NA
1      5668        rs21   C      T      NA
1      5680        rs61   A      G      NA
```

For all rows in "Illumina", I get NAs

I don't get why am I not getting:

```
CHR    POSITION    SNP    REF    ALT    Illumina
1      49554       rs53   A      G      1:1000122-GT
1      564672      rs56   A      C      10:1000111-CT
1      5668        rs21   C      T      10:10004568-TCTC-T
1      5680        rs61   A      G      10:100065656-GA
```

When I do left_join the other way around:

```
C = left_join(B, A, by = "SNP")
```

I get only NAs in CHR, POSITION, REF & ALT columns

I am using RStudio Version 1.0.136, R version 3.3.2

Please help !

**SOLUTION**

The problem was that A.txt had columns separated by ", ". I removed the commas and changed sep="," to sep=" " in read.table("A.txt") and everything worked fine.

Old A.txt

```
CHR, POSITION, SNP, REF, ALT
1, 49554, rs53, A, G
1, 564672, rs56, A, C
1, 5668, rs21, C, T
1, 5680, rs61, A, G
```

Comment: Using your code, it gives me the results desired.

Comment: Are you sure, your SNP columns are in the same format?

Comment: `A <- fread('CHR    POSITION    SNP    REF    ALT
1      49554       rs53   A      G
            ')
B <- fread('Illumina        SNP
10:1000122-GT   rs53
             ')
left_join(A, B, by = "SNP")`. Gives the output desired

Comment: Maybe some more rows, could reveal the problem?

Comment: Do a `str(A)` and `str(B)` to see if it reveals anything different regarding the classes of your columns.

Comment: Hi @sequoia, yes, all columns are characters in A and B.

Comment: Hi @Linus, I just added a few more rows

Comment: Hi @KS89, nothing particularly different. I did lapply(A, class) and lapply(B, class) and both of them show that in A & B columns are only characters

Comment: I tried it with the more rows, but still get the correct result :-/

Comment: Hi @Linus, I just edited how I imported the data

Comment: Why do convert the results again to a `data.frame`? `read.table` already returns a data.frame. In addition. You can set `stringAsFactor` for the complete script using `options(stringAsFactor=F)` I doubt this will help, but maybe worth a try :-)

Comment: Thank you @Linus, I solved the problem. Please see the edited post.

Comment: It is funny. Now that I posted the solution, I get down votes. If I had not done it, I would have some up votes and some helpful & nice people would be wasting their time finding the solution. Under that logic, I should not have posted the solution and kept these upvotes...does not make much sense for me...

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer. You can accept it after minimal wait. Adding a solution to a question does not make the question better if it was already downvote worthy. I see a long sequence of comments so you were not clear. And you should clarify via post edit, not comment. Also questions re code need a [mcve]. Note that your question would not have had to be asked had you prepared one because preparing/echoing the input would have shown the problem. Which was an obvious thing to check just from reading your question, hence too from writing it. Downvotes appropriate. (I didn't.)